# Connect SQL Server with Next.js

Tags: node.js, sql-server, next.js

I am having a problem **(ConnectionError)** while trying to connect Next.js with SQL Server with `mssql`, I have enabled **TCP/IP**, and **SQL Server Browser** is running.

this is my code:

```js
// db.js

import sql from 'mssql'

// connection configs
const config = {
    user: 'test',
    password: '1000',
    server: '.\sqlexpress',
    database: 'DATABASE_NAME',
    port: 1433,
    options: {
        instancename: 'SQLEXPRESS',
        trustedconnection: true,
        trustServerCertificate: true
    },
}

export default async function ExcuteQuery(query, options) {
    try {
        let pool = await sql.connect(config);
        let products = await pool.request().query(query);
        return products.recordsets;
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

```js
// api/hello.js
import ExcuteQuery from '../../utils/db';

export default async function handler(req, res) {

  console.log(await ExcuteQuery('select * from tbl_category'));

  res.status(200).json({})
}
```

this is the error:

```
ConnectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND .
    at E:\0 - WEB\pos\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\connection-pool.js:70:17
    at Connection.onConnect (E:\0 - WEB\pos\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1012:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
    at Connection.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Connection.emit (E:\0 - WEB\pos\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1040:18)
    at E:\0 - WEB\pos\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1081:16       
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11) {
  code: 'EINSTLOOKUP',
  originalError: ConnectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND .
      at E:\0 - WEB\pos\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1081:32     
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11) {
    code: 'EINSTLOOKUP',
    isTransient: undefined
  }
}
```

also these are the settings changed:

[image: TCP/IP enabled]
[image: TCP/IP Ip addresses]
[image: SQL Server Browser]

Comment: I think the `server` should be the ip address

Comment: @Ajex you mean like **127.0.0.1**?

Comment: I suppose if you are running it locally. You can first try connecting to it with SSMS

Comment: https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/connect-to-the-sql-server/

Comment: @Ajex tried **MY_DESKTOP_NAME\SQLEXPRESS** but it didn't work, so I disabled and re-enabled everything and that worked

Comment: The SQL Browser service, responsible for instance name resolution, only loads the server protocol settings as it starts. i.e.: If you change the server protocol settings you need to restart the SQL Browser service to detect the new configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried setting the server to **MY_DESKTOP_NAME\SQLEXPRESS** but it didn't work, but after disabling and reenabling all the settings it works now, it  was kinda like a glitch in the system

Comment: I am stuck here, can you help me on how to connect Next js with SQL server using windows authentication

Comment: @MONEYMSN actually i don't think it's a good idea to use Windows Authentication, but try creating a new user for that database and connect through it

Comment: Tried connecting using server authentication too but same error, can you paste the working code and steps to be followed which will be usefull

Comment: I have a database with a login user to it so I don't use Windows Authentication, then you need to find the right server name just like how I mentioned in this question and the answer, then i use a connection string like so: `"Server=SERVERNAME;Database=DATABASE;User Id=USER;Password=USERPASSWORD;Encrypt=false"`, then i pass it to connect function like this: `let pool = await sql.connect(CONNECTIONSTRING)`, so instead of the config object in the question, i use a connection string

Comment: Thanks, I have a solution for server authentication.